# How to migrate existing java based cucumber test framework to Karate

Tags: cucumber, karate, cucumber-java

Karate recently released GUI Automation feature. I always liked the karate way of writing script. I'm thinking to implement Karate's unified framework for Rest + GUI at larger scale in my org.

**Problem statement**: The existing teams uses purely cucumber based framework and have automated significant number of tests. In order to migrate Karate framework we will need to re write automated tests with Karate's standards. It would take huge efforts to migrate existing tests considering volume of work. I am just looking for best possible ways to migrate with minimum efforts.

*Is there a way I can add Karate to my existing cucumber based framework so that I can keep existing tests running while writing new tests with karate guidelines.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible (in theory) to mix Karate and Cucumber in the same Maven (or Gradle) project. Unfortunately I don't know of too many people who have done this.

Please refer to this discussion for more: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/444#issuecomment-419852761

Sorry I can't provide a more clearer answer, you may need to experiment a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply. I will surely go through the link you shared.